# Match array key with regex is not working in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have array like this

```
Array (
    [test.0.male_min_months] => Array (
        [0] => The test.0.male_min_months field has a duplicate value.
    )
    [test.42.male_min_months] => Array (
        [0] => The test.42.male_min_months field has a duplicate value.
    )
    [name] => Array (
        [0] => The name field is required.
    )
    [unit_id] => Array (
        [0] => The unit id field is required.
    )
)
```

And a function to check key in array is

```
function preg_array_key_exists($pattern, $array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    return $array[preg_grep($pattern,$keys)[0]];
}
```

Its working for `preg_array_key_exists('/(test.0.male)/',$my_array);`

But not working for `preg_array_key_exists('/(test.42.male)/',$my_array);`

Comment: Feel free to downvote but please explain.

Comment: Have you seen: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php#111673 ?

Answer (score 0):

I will explain why/where the code is failing and provide a solution.

When you call `array_keys()` inside your custom function, each key becomes a value with an indexed (auto-incremented) key.

When you call `preg_grep($pattern,$keys)`, it creates an array of matches and preserves the numeric key.  Specifically for your case, `"test.42.male_min_months"` has a key of `1`.

This means `return $array[preg_grep($pattern,$keys)[0]]` will only be successful when your pattern asks for the key of the first sub-array in `$my_array`.

To correct your existing function, use:

```
current(preg_grep($pattern,$keys));
```

This will return the first value in the sub-array that matches your key pattern.

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0618d5f9e4ee07ca1e13cc984d5e93059706c607) with var_export to explain the issue):

```
<?php
$my_array=array(
    "test.0.male_min_months"=>array(
        0=>"The test.0.male_min_months field has a duplicate value."
    ),
    "test.42.male_min_months"=>array(
        0=>"The test.42.male_min_months field has a duplicate value.",
    ),
    "name"=>array(
        0=>"The name field is d."
    ),
    "unit_id"=>array(
        0=>"The unit id field is d."
    )
);

function preg_array_key_exists($pattern,$array){
    $keys = array_keys($array);  // create new indexed array holding each key as a value
    return $array[current(preg_grep($pattern,$keys))];
}

$pattern="/(test.42.male)/";  // your regex pattern (which doesn't fail you)
// $pattern="/(test\.42\.male)/";  // escape the literal dots, as a matter of good practice    
$output=preg_array_key_exists($pattern,$my_array);
```

p.s. As a matter of good practice, when using literal dots in your regex, escape them like this `\.`

The output is:

```
array (
  0 => 'The test.42.male_min_months field has a duplicate value.',
)
```

Comment: @detective404 If my answer sufficiently solves your problem please award it the green tick so that your question is removed from the unanswered questions list and so future readers don't waste time solving a resolved question.  If something is still not right, please let me know.